# memoir class: vertically locate side panel text to marker in main text

Tags: memoir, verse, sidenotes

I'm using memoir to write verse. In side-panels I put quotes or images that relate to specific places in the verse. Ideally I'd like to put a marker in the verse  which would locate where, in the side-panel, the quotes or images should appear (eg, the vertical location from the header). The side-panel on a recto page is on the right side; on a verso page it is one the left side. So for a long poem the marker would need allow for this. Any ideas or pointers to related ideas would be much appreciated. Thank you. ... Gary

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full, but minimal example, such that others have something to work with

Comment: By "side panel" do you mean the marginpar area?  Alternatively, you can use paracol (and geometry) to create a synchronized two-column page.

Comment: Take a look at the `marginnote` package (if I understood your question correctly, it should do exactly what you want).

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Do you want to print a marker in the verse and a matching one in the margin?  `memoir` provides for a range of side notes with varying default positions (current position with or without overlap; starting at the top or bottom of the page). It seems to me that it would be very hard, and of limited use, to produce something where you could specify the exact location of a side note from the regular text, where you would have to determine the position of the marker in the text and then ensure the note is positioned vertically accordingly.

Comment: Thanks to all who replied. I will take a look at the paracol and marginnote packages. As for terminology, yes, I was using "side-panel" for margin notes. I had in mind something like \footnote, except a \marginnote. You'd mark the verse with \marginnote and then the note would be put into the margin directly horizontal to where \marginnote appeared in the verse. The verse I write uses the margin notes to provide images or quotations that bear on specific words in the verse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from your comment and noting that you use `memoir` then use `\footnote` for your notes after having first specified `\footnotesinmargin` which puts footnotes into the margin instead of at the bottom of the page. To revert to footnotes at the bottom use `\footnotesatfoot`. See the manual (`> texdoc memoir`) Chapter 12 for more information on this and other marginal note styles.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

\footnotesinmargin

A verse line\footnote{A footnote in the margin}

\footnotesatfoot

Regular text with a footnote\footnote{At bottom}.
\end{document}
```

You may want to increase the size of the font used for footnotes in your particular case which is covered in Chapter 12.